# A 4-dimensional algebra over a field is a division algebra iff it doesn't have zerodivisors iff it's not a matrix algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $A$ a $4$-dimensional $F$-algebra. Can I classify all such algebras as being either $\operatorname{Mat}_2(F)$ or a division algebra depending on whether they have zero divisors?

I'm not sure if the following is a proof. I think it depends on $A$ being a simple algebra, which I'm not sure if it comes for free from $\dim_F A =4$. Could someone verify or generalize?

If $A$ has a zero divisor, it can't be a division algebra. By Wedderburn's theorem, it is a matrix algebra over some division algebra $D$. But because the $\dim_F A = 2^2$, we necessarily have $\dim_F D =1$. So $A$ is a matrix algebra.

Conversely, Wedderburn's theorem still implies that $A=\operatorname{Mat}_n(D)$ even if $A$ doesn't have zero divisors. But then $n$ must be $1$, so $A$ is a division algebra.

Comment: $F \times F \times F \times F$ is a 4-dimensional $F$-algebra which is neither $\mathrm{Mat}_2(F)$ nor a division algebra.

Comment: Not all finite dimensional algebras are semisimple. $F[x]/(x^4)$ is a 4-dimensional algebra that is not a (product of) matrix algebra(s) over division algebra(s) D.